# How to track a single Xen VM's I/O utilization

Tags: monitoring, xen, io

What is a good way to monitor I/O individually for Xen Virtual Machines (not Dom0)?

Comment: Disk IO? If so - what is your disk-setup for the DomU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

1) xentop (and drill down on I/O)

2) monitoring tools like xenmon (http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2005/HPL-2005-187.html)

3) Standard I/O monitoring tools that you would normally use should give a good indication of the I/O usage of the guest as well.

Comment: No way to do that by Xen Api ?